# Error when starting monerod: Failed to open db handle for m_blocks : MDB_CORRUPTED : Located page was wrong type

Tags: monerod, lmdb

Every time I try to run monerod, I get the following error:

```
Failed to open db handle for m_blocks : MDB_CORRUPTED : Located page was wrong type
```

[image: Command prompt window snippet]

It briefly displays, and then shuts down the command prompt window.

What can I do to fix this?

Note: re-post of a question asked on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5en4zx/getting_an_error_every_time_i_run_monerod/).

Comment: Probably not much can be done to fix that besides deleting the LMDB directory and resyncing from scratch. But before you do that I'd like to get a copy of your data.mdb file for dissection.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that this means blockchain database (LMDB) corruption.

The easiest way to fix it is to rename your corrupt `lmdb` folder to something else, for example:

Rename `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` to `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb-old` and run `monerod` again.

It should start without errors and it will again create a fresh copy of `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` and sync from scratch. It will take some time to catch up with the network again, though.

Also, if you don't mind, please make a .zip archive of the `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb-old` and upload somewhere for Monero dev. [hyc](https://www.reddit.com/user/hyc_symas), who is the creator of LMDB database, to examine (don't worry, your wallet data is not stored there, it's safe to share). This will help to understand why it had been corrupted and possibly prevent such occurances in the future.

At the end, when all is working, you can safely delete the `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb-old`

Note: the example above is for Windows systems and default settings. On other systems, you'd need to locate your `\lmdb` folder and do practically the same, just at different folder location.